# How to use Firebase Dynamic Links in a Flutter application?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase Dynamic Links in my Flutter application.

Everything works perfect on Android - when the user clicks the received dynamic link the app will open if installed or the Play Store if not installed (and the data from the dynamic link is received in the firebase callbacks).

**The problem is on iOS - If the app is installed is not automatically opened when the users clicks the dynamic link and the callbacks are not called.**

Note: also on iOS works if the app is not installed (the App Store will open and after the app is installed the callbacks are being called).

**Here you can find my Dynamic Links implementation**

[image]